# iOs screen orientation problems on Smartface Emulator

Tags: smartface.io

I developed an *iOS WebView* application which includes YouTube videos.

Videos are playing normal, but I've got a problem: my app doesn't use accelerometer sensors and the orientation is always portrait.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , you should set AccelerometerStatus .

basically;

`Device.setAccelerometerStatus(true);`
( http://docs.smartface.io/html/M_Device_setAccelerometerStatus.htm )

Than, you can use onAccelerate event;

```
 var varAccX = 0;
 var varAccY = 0;
 var varAccZ = 0;
function Global_Events_OnAccelerate(e){
 varAccX = e.x;
varAccY = e.y;
varAccZ = e.z;
}
```

( http://docs.smartface.io/?topic=html/E_Device_onAccelerate.htm )

More sensor features also will be available they are in RoadMap http://www.smartface.io/roadmap/

You can change the orientation from Project Details.

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/get-started/project-details/#appsettings

Comment: Thanks for variable informotion. But i don't know how to use them forchange screen orientation. Actually can we talk from mail?